# Unity error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just started programing and I'm following a tutorial on how to make a game in unity
So i did everything just like the video said but I'm still getting this error
Can please somebody explain what i did wrong?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float playerSpeed = 500;
    public float directionalSpeed = 20;

    void Start()
    {
       // Start is called before the first frame update            
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
#if UNITY_EDITOR || UNITY_STANDALONE || UNITY_WEBPLAYER
        .transform.position.y, gameObject.transform.position.z), directionalSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
#endif
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(gameObject.transform.position, new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(gameObject.transform.position.x + moveHorizontal, -2.5f, 2.5f), gameObject
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.forward * playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        //Mobile Controls
        Vector2 touch = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition + new Vector3(0, 0, 10f));
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {    
           transform.position + new Vector3(touch.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);            
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that also this `transform.position + ...` does absolutely nothing ... It would return a new `Vector3` but the result is nowhere stored ... you probably wanted to make this a `+=` or only `=` instead to actually move the object?

Answer (score 0):

In fact the code that you will get is:

```cs
void Update() {
.transform.position.y, ...), directionalSpeed * ...);
}
```

And this is not valid. That's why.